# Tangent subtraction and addition

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan18^\circ - \cot36^\circ + \tan72^\circ - \cot54^\circ = ?$$

I tried to transform them and used $\sin/\cos$ but the operation gets longer and longer. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you use $\cot(90^\circ-x)=\tan x$ and $\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x$ you get $\tan 18^\circ =\cot 72^\circ=\dfrac{1}{\tan 72^\circ}$ and similar stuff for $54^\circ$ and $36^\circ$. Then it might be easier to compute perhaps with the forumla for $\tan(2x)$.

Comment: I tried it too but it's still complex and long

Comment: Well, if confronted with the general, impossible problem of expressing $\tan\alpha+\tan\beta-\cot\gamma-\cot\delta$ as radicals, it's pretty damn short and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $\tan 18^\circ = t$.  Then you need
$$t-\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+\frac1t-\frac{1-t^2}{2t} = \frac{1-2t^2-3t^4}{2t(1-t^2)}$$

To find $t$, you may want to use $36=90-54 \implies$
$$\tan(2\cdot18^\circ)=\cot(3\cdot18^\circ) \implies \frac{2t}{1-t^2}=\frac{1-3t^2}{3t-t^3}$$
Solve the biquadratic and select the right root!

Answer (score 0):

After reducing it gave (to me) a surprising over-simplification:

$$ \tan18^\circ - \cot36^\circ + \tan72^\circ - \cot54^\circ =  4 \tan18^\circ $$

EDIT1:

(starting  a separate question)